# AND within OR within AND in Excel function?

Tags: excel, syntax, excel-formula

I need to check if a A is over 200, and if B is over 150, if that's the case, the result should be true.

However, if A is exactly 200, it still has to result in true is B is over 100.

In short

```
A>200 AND B>150 = True
```

But if

```
A=200 AND B>100 = True
A=200 AND B<=100 = False
```

I tried it myself, but I'm stuck, my brain can't handle all the nesting, and I think I'm missing something easy, I also think the syntax I'm using is not correct, but what I came up with so far is:

```
=IF(AND(A>200;B>150;OR(AND(A=200;B>100);"True";"False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a math-logic question, but anyway, this should help with more complex scenarios as well, especially if you are having difficulty grasping the different outcomes.

I would draw a probability tree, similar to the below, showing all the different outcomes for each:

```
         A              B
                ----  > 150  -- True
                |
 ----  > 200  --|
 |              |
 |              ----  <=150  -- False
 |
 |              ----  > 100  -- True
 |              |
-|---  = 200  --|
 |              |
 |              ----  <= 100 -- False
 |
 |
 ----  < 200  ----- Anything -- False
```

Once this is correct, gather the ones we need. In this case, we need to separate the True from the False. The simplest way would be to work on the True (2 out of the 5 outcomes are True, so less work!)

Follow each 'True' branch, and `AND` them:

```
AND(A>200;B>150)
AND(A=200;B>100)
```

Once you got everything, `OR` them together:

```
OR(AND(A>200;B>150);AND(A=200;B>100))
```

So final result:

```
IF(OR(AND(A>200;B>150);AND(A=200;B>100)); "True"; "False")
```

---

**Extra**: if you wanted to get the "False" instead:

Follow each 'False' branch, and `AND` them (note since the last one is alone, we can drop the `AND`):

```
AND(A>200;B<=150)
AND(A=200;B<=100)
A<200
```

Once you got everything, `OR` them together:

```
OR(AND(A>200;B<=150);AND(A=200;B<=100);A<200)
```

So final result:

```
IF(OR(AND(A>200;B<=150);AND(A=200;B<=100);A<200); "False"; "True")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
= IF(OR(AND(A=200;B>100);AND(A>200;B>150));"True";"False")
```

Just a tip for future reference: Generally, if several separate conditions can return "true", several `AND` statements within a single `OR` statement is what you should use. Of course there are some exceptions to this, but this is the general guideline to follow.