# Multiple IF AND Statments with 2 Possible Outputs

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Jerry, to answer your first comment, no, the outcome should be a PASS because B5 has a value of -12790 and C5 has a value of -12790 making their absolute max difference 0. When I asked before, I changed C5 to 0 and left B5 at -12790 which made the absolute max difference 12790. This case should be a FAIL. I apologize for not explaining in more detail. It is a bit tricky to explain, but I really do appreciate your help with this. I think we are on the right track and I have been trying for a very long time to figure this formula out when I have some spare time.  Let me try to explain what I am trying to accomplish here. Row 3 has 4 cells labeled as Lw_Send / Lw_Return / Up_Send / Up_Return. These 4 hands are part of one robot and each hand must be taught individually. Each hand has 4 movable axis or joints that can be adjusted. The 4 joints are X-axis (forward and reverse movement), Z-axis (vertical movement), Y-axis (horizontal or left and right movement) and Theta axis (rotational movement). The only axis’s I am concerned with in this problem are the Y and theta axis’s. These two axis have a direct effect on one another meaning if I shift the Y-axis one direction, it will shift my theta axis and vice versa. This is why we have rules when we are adjusting the Y-axis and theta axis. When I am done with teaching the Lw_Send hand (B5:B9), I start teaching the Lw_Return hand (C5:C9). Before I can complete my teaching of this hand, I must compare my theta and Y-axis teach values with my teach values of the 1st hand, the Lw-Send hand. For example, if B5 has a teach value of -12790 and C5 has a teach value of -12792, this means my absolute max difference between the two hand theta axis’s is 2. With the theta difference being 2, when I look at the salmon colored delta table, it says that my Y-axis teach difference between the 1st and 2nd  hand must be an absolute max difference of 15-20.This means that if B5 is -75506 then cell C5 can be within the range of [-75491 to -75486] or [-75521 to -75526]. The ultimate goal is to of course have no deviation between the hands. This is almost never possible. Once those two hands are done, I must apply this same rule for the third and fourth hand. As I continue to teach each hand, I must compare my theta and horizontal teach values with that of all the previous hands. This is why it is very important to use the absolute max difference. One hand might be more positive and another hand might be more negative.  Please let me know if this better explains what I am trying to accomplish. Again, I really do appreciate your help with this nightmare



Been beating my head against the wall trying to figure this one out. I'm trying to have multiple IF AND statements within a cell.

1.) the absolute max of B5:C5 must be less than or equal to 5 when the absolute max of B7:C7 is less than or equal to 2. Whether or not it meets the criteria will be displayed as PASS or FAIL. That's the first rule.

2.)The second rule in the same cell needs to be the absolute max of B5:C5 must be less than or equal to 4 when the absolute max of B7:C7 is between or equal to 3 through 8.

3.) The third rule needs to be the absolute max of B5:C5 must be less than or equal to 3 when the absolute max of B7:C7 is between or equal to 9 through 14.

4.) The fourth rule needs to be the absolute max of B5:C5 must be less than or equal to 2 when the absolute max of B7:C7 is between or equal to 15 through 20.

5.) The fifth rule needs to be the absolute max of B5:C5 must be less than or equal to 1 when the absolute max of B7:C7 is between or equal to 21 through 26.

6.) The sixth rule needs to be the absolute max of B5:C5 must be equal to 0 when the absolute max of B7:C7 is between or equal to 27 through 30.

Their is a snip of my spreadsheet below. If you look at the salmon colored table for delta Y and delta theta, you can see how the values in my rules apply to cells B5:C5 and B7:C7.

I would greatly appreciate any help :)

So far, here is what I've got for the first two rules:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C5)," ",IF(OR(AND(MAX(ABS(B5:C5<=5))),(MAX(ABS(B7:C7<=2))),"PASS","FAIL",OR(MAX(ABS(B5:C5<=4))),(MAX(ABS(B7:C7<=8)))),"PASS","FAIL"))
```

***Screenshot***
[image: Robot Teaching Data]

Comment: The best way I find to build formulas is in multiple cells, so that you can see exactly which part of the final formula is producing which results.  When a formula gets lengthy (and with multiple nested If's and other functions), it can be near-impossible to troubleshooting as a single entity.   ,,, I would be interested to see **all** of your criteria together, along with sample data, and a short description of what you're starting with, as well as the end-goal....the best answer to your problem could be very different depending on these factors.

Comment: I answered [something a bit similar a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307480/1578604). Maybe it could be of use? For your specific case however, I think you might want to create a table listing similar outcomes and lookup there each time you need to test the final outcome.

Comment: Hi Ashlee, thank you for your response. I updated my original problem to include all 6 criteria as well as added in a snip of my spreadsheet.

Comment: @VincentShelby - just looking at your latest edit, the value that is of interest to you is in fact the absolute difference? You'd get that by using simply `ABS(B5-C5)`

Comment: What isn't clear to me: You have 6 conditions, if 3 pass and 3 fail is that an overall fail? What if 1 passes and 5 fail?

Comment: @Barry only one of the 6 condition can pass. Their are 6 different condition options to achieve a pass.

Comment: OK, I get it now - didn't look closely enough.....I posted an answer - Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment, I would use a lookup table:

[image]

If there is a 'match' from the table, then `SUMPRODUCT` will give a number above 0, thus will be 'Pass'.

The formula from the picture is as follows:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((ABS(MAX(A11:B11))<=$B$3:$B$8)*(ABS(MAX(C11:D11))>=$C$3:$C$8)*(ABS(MAX(C11:D11))<=$D$3:$D$8))>0,"Pass","Fail")
```

Multiplication is equivalent to 'AND', so in the above, the 3 different conditions are being 'AND'-ed to each other. If all 3 passes on any row from the lookup table, then the formula returns 'Pass'.

---

EDIT: If you really meant 'max absolute' instead of 'absolute max', then you would need this formula instead (this one has to be an array entered formula entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((MAX(ABS(A11:B11))<=$B$3:$B$8)*(MAX(ABS(C11:D11))>=$C$3:$C$8)*(MAX(ABS(C11:D11))<=$D$3:$D$8))>0,"Pass","Fail")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry! I'm going to put this table together and give it a try :)

Comment: I added a picture of the table I created from your table above. the cell that I am trying to get a PASS or FAIL result in is F5. With B5 at -12790 and C5 changed to 0, I should get a FAIL in F5. What did I input incorrectly from the formula?

Comment: Hi Jerry, I changed the cells you suggested and the result in cell F5 came back as FAIL. Please see the screen I posted below your screens.

Comment: Please see my first post at the top. I added in my response to your question as well as much more detail. I apologize for it looking like slop. I couldn't send you a private message or move this conversation to a chat

Comment: Is their a way for me to send just you my spreadsheet? It might be easier for you if you can actually see everything

Comment: After discussion, the problem was different from the one presented in the question, and a proper working solution was provided outside StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (ignoring the ISBLANK(C5) and concentrating on the different pairs of criteria)

```
=IF(OR(
          AND(MAX(ABS(B5:C5))>5, MAX(ABS(B7:C7))<=2),
          AND(MAX(ABS(B5:C5))>4, MAX(ABS(B7:C7))>=3, MAX(ABS(B7:C7))<=8)
      ),"FAIL","PASS")
```

Entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> since it's an array formula.

Basically if any of the parts of the OR() evaluate to true then that triggers a FAIL result.

NOTE: when entering a complex formula you can use Ctrl+Enter in the formula bar to arrange and indent the formula across multiple lines: it makes it a lot easier to follow.  Drag the bottom of the formula bar down so you can see the whole thing.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. I tried inputting the formula you recommended, but no success. I've further explained how the criteria in my formula needs to be in my original problem statement. Their are 6 possible outcomes for a PASS or FAIL result based on the criteria in my first statement.

Comment: What does "no success" look like exactly? Result/no result/error?

Comment: Are you using Ctrl+Shift+Enter?  It's an array formula so you need that.  I assumed you were already using that.

Comment: originally I had it as an array formula, but I've been messing with it so much I lost track :/ I changed it to an array formula and it came back with "FAIL"    I'm going to try Jerry's suggestion below with building a lookup table

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

`=IF(ABS(B5-C5)<=6-MATCH(ABS(B7-C7),{0,3,9,15,21,27}),"Pass","Fail")`

There may be some "edge cases" where that doesn't work - please test and let me know.

This formula uses the absolute difference of `B7` and `C7` in the `MATCH` function to find the value that needs to be met by the absolute difference of `B5` and `C5`